# Recommended way to deal with updating m2m table postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have the below tables

1. A project table

   project_id,project_name
2. A skill table

   skill_id,skill_name
3. A project_skill table (many to many relationship)

   project_skill_id,project_id,skill_id

The browser will have a form which asks the user to enter a project name and and SO style autocomplete for tags. I'm sending the below json format back to sql for insertion

```
{"project_name":"foo","skills":["bar","baz"]}
```

My question relates to a situation where the user gets to edit an existing project.Assuming the user removes "baz" from skills and includes "zed". How do i properly deal with updating the many to many table

```
{"project_name":"foo","skills":["bar","zed","biz"]}
```

1. Do i remove all records from the m2m table and do a fresh insert with the new skills?

   - remove all records based on project_id
   - insert new records of bar,zed,biz
2. Do i check in the server what was removed/added and remove only what was actually removed

   - remove baz from table
   - add biz

This also pertains to modifying project_name etc. Do i check what was modified and update the necessary or perform a complete delete and insert

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a CTE with a MERGE (note this is SQL Server but Postgres should be similar):

```
;WITH src AS
(
    SELECT p.project_id, s.skill_id
    FROM
    dbo.project AS p
    INNER JOIN @input AS i ON p.project_name = i.project_name
    INNER JOIN dbo.skill AS s ON i.skill_name = s.skill_name
)
MERGE INTO dbo.project_skill AS tgt
USING src
ON tgt.project_id = src.project_id AND tgt.skill_id = src.skill_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (project_id, skill_id) VALUES (src.project_id, src.skill_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;
```

where @input contains the new values:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE
(
    project_name VARCHAR(100),
    skill_name VARCHAR(100)
);
```